# TSQL Grouping problems

Tags: t-sql

I've been given a TSQL table an extract of which is below

```
Serial Number   Code 1  Code 2   Code 3
15872           1242    NULL     NULL
15872           NULL    558      222
99955           995     452      NULL
```

I'd like to group these four fields together to form the following output

```
Serial Number   Code 1  Code 2   Code 3
15872           1242    558      222
99955           995     452      NULL
```

This looks a simple problem, but I just can't get it right.  Any advice would be very much appreciated!

Kind regards,

DJ

Answer (score 0):

You need to use aggregate function in conjunction with [Coalesce](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql) function , something like this :

```
select Serial , COALESCE(SUM(code1),0),COALESCE(SUM(code2),0),COALESCE(SUM(code3),0)
from yourTable
group by Serial
```

This basically replaces `NULL` as `0` so that you can calculate `SUM` as intended

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 0):

Oh...misread question twice, haha.

```
CREATE TABLE #X
(
    SerialNumber INT
    , Code1 INT
    , Code2 INT
    , Code3 INT
)
INSERT INTO #X
VALUES
    (15872, 1242, NULL, NULL)
    , (15872, NULL, 558, 222)
    , (99955, 995, 452, NULL)

SELECT
    [SerialNumber]
    , MAX([Code1]) AS [Code1]
    , MAX([Code2]) AS [Code2]
    , MAX([Code3]) AS [Code3]
FROM #x
GROUP BY [SerialNumber]
```

Now, you've not mentioned anything about an aggregate so this assumes that there is only one row that can possibly have the value i.e. this doesn't exist:

```
Serial Number   Code 1  Code 2   Code 3
15872           1242    773      NULL
15872           NULL    558      222
```